# how can I know if a file on ftp server is hidden file?

Tags: c#, ftp

i have a file stored on the dtp server.
the server is set to show hidden files.
is there a way (using C#)
to know if the file has hidden attribute?

I see a way to get last modified
and a way to get file size
check sum and so on.

but no way to get if file is hidden

i mean using FTP protocol for example FtpWebRequest or Rebex.Net.Ftp

Comment: Type `chmod filename` and add the output to your question

Comment: The problem is that, depending on the FTP server software, it might not allow a client to see hidden files. Some servers allow you to send `ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails + " -al";`. If its a Linux server, then any file that starts with a `.` is a hidden file. Depending on the server software though, you might not be able to execute this command.

Comment: The server allows hidden files.  Where is it defined that there is a "."  on hidden files?

Comment: @NahumLitvin - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory

Answer (score 0):

FileAttributes should solve your problem

```
 if((file.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden){
    //Is hidden
}
```

'file' is the variable name for you file

Comment: I mean a file that I get using FTP protocol.

Comment: If you don't have the whole file you must first make sure that you get the files attributes.

Comment: Hiw can i get the hidden attribute using ftp?